# Can you generalize a function?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, modeling, splines, function

I'm currently working my way through some Machine Learning courses and books, and from what I can understand, ML uses a stock of standard functions that are
used over and over again. This led me to ask, is there a way to generalise a function instead of specifying it? For example, instead of using linear or logistic or polynomial regression, create an ML algorithm to approximate the best
type of function? Is such a thing possible mathematically?

Comment: you could look into splines ...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model

Answer (score 0):

Look into [splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) which is a quite flexible modeling tool. For instance [Flexible and inflexible models in machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69237/flexible-and-inflexible-models-in-machine-learning).